# ChatBot Application template is missing from Visual Studio

Tags: botframework

I am new to ChatBot developent , in all the tutorials I checked so far starts an example with template ChatBot Application, I do not see this in my visual studio 2017 community edition, I only see the following Templates , Am I missing something , if I use any of these templates I do not see any references to IDialog interfaces. Any leads would be of great help.Thanks

1. Microsoft Bot Builder V4 SDK
2. Echo Bot
3. Empty Bot

Comment: Could you please link to the tutorials you mention? Possibly there is a difference between the templates for the V3 and V4 SDK.

Comment: Here is the one https://tutorials.botsfloor.com/creating-a-bot-using-c-and-microsoft-bot-framework-a344420f9d6f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorial you mentioned are about Bot Framework v3, which is now an "old" version.

Bot Framework v4 templates for Visual Studio are available through `Visual Studio Marketplace`, here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BotBuilder.botbuilderv4

[image: VS template]

Once you install those templates, you will see the following project types:

[image: Templates v4]

Answer (score 1):

I tried to search it on but not found the template so I upload the template I have on mega and here is the link: https://mega.nz/#!LREzRaoL!gdVVLXg46ya5JbD8DcscWO7m-30wSmBp1yvagpjXZx0

Then copy the zip file into Documents -> Visual Studio 2017 (That's the version of VS I'm using) -> Templates -> Project Templates -> Visual C#

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v597y.png)

[And there is the template on Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjlGA.png)

Comment: Note: This is for the previous version, Bot Framework v3.

Answer (score 0):

the latest update in Visual Studio 2017 v15.9.7 is under Cloud > Azure Bot Services.

[image: Bot Template v4]